# how to mock and test inside/outside get and set methods?

Tags: testing, mocking, mockito, junit5, assertion

I don`t know why but I`m always getting NullPointer and no idea why and how exactly this test should looks like. Its about method: webServiceTemplate():

```
@Configuration
public class ErdConfiguration {
    
    @Autowired
    private EJwtProperties eJwtProperties;
    
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        // this package must match the package in the <generatePackage> specified in pom.xml
        marshaller.setContextPath("erdUserRoles.wsdl");
        return marshaller;
    }

    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller());
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller());
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(eJwtProperties.getRoles().getErdServiceUri());
    
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }
}
```

and EJwtProperties class which it uses:

```
public class EJwtProperties {
private Map<String, String> claims = new HashMap<>();
private String signingKey;
private SourceTokenConfig sourceToken = new SourceTokenConfig();
private RolesConfig roles = new RolesConfig();
private List<String> generateEjwtRoles = Collections.emptyList();
private boolean cacheDisabled = false;

@Data
public static class SourceTokenConfig {
    private boolean embedSourceToken = false;
    private String embeddedTokenClaimName = "source-token";
}

@Data
public static class RolesConfig {
    private boolean rolesEnabled = false;
    private String rolesClaimName = "roles";
    private String erdAppId;
    private String erdServiceUri;
}
}
```

My code so far looks like this and got null pointer while Im trying to check getRoles() in when-thenReturn :

```
    @Mock
    private EJwtProperties eJwtProperties;

    @InjectMocks
    private ErdConfiguration underTest;

    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void webServiceTemplateTest() {

        EJwtProperties.RolesConfig roles = new EJwtProperties.RolesConfig();
        roles.setErdServiceUri("testErdServiceUri");
        
        eJwtProperties.setRoles(roles);
        
        underTest = new ErdConfiguration();
    
        when(eJwtProperties.getRoles()).thenReturn(roles);  //this one passed
            when(eJwtProperties.getRoles().getErdServiceUri()).thenReturn(roles.getErdServiceUri()); //here nullPointer

     //   underTest.webServiceTemplate();  //this is what I was planning to do next
//assertEquals(underTest.webServiceTemplate(), eJwtProperties.getRoles().getErdServiceUri());  //or this
//        assertEquals(marshaller, underTest.webServiceTemplate().getMarshaller());
//        assertEquals(marshaller, underTest.webServiceTemplate().getUnmarshaller());
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that I'm still learning tests. Id be thankful for any help. How the hack it should looks like? What am I missing that it return null ? Should I initialize whole properties??

Comment: Please add the missing parts of your test class since the correct annotations for Spring test support make all the difference.

Comment: what exactly you want me to add? in test class only 1st line is missing: "class ErdConfigurationTest {"